# Google PubSub getMessageID = null because of wrong tag?

Tags: google-app-engine, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am having some difficulty getting the message ID from a pubsub message in my subscriber. The issue appears to be that the pubsub message is storing the ID in the message_id field but the getMessageId method is looking for the message id in a non-existent messageId field.

I am trying to get the message ID from a Pubsub message that was publish from another app. The JSON request body looks like this:

```
{
    "message": {
        "data": "SomeEncodedDate",
        "attributes": {
            "Published_Timestamp": "1438970954798"
        },
        "message_id": "1325068255839"
    },
    "subscription": "projects/MyProject/subscriptions/MySubscription"
}
```

I can successfully recreate the message with the following code:

```java
JsonParser parser = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().createJsonParser(jsonRequest);
parser.skipToKey("message");
PubsubMessage message = parser.parseAndClose(PubsubMessage.class);
```

If I look at the message in the debugger it has the valid message ID in the message_id field. However, getMessageId() returns null. If I use the method setMessageId("SomeKey") the message will then contain a new field of messageId with the new value. Now my message has two ID fields, message_id and messageId. Calling getMessageId now returns the messageId field value and not the message_id that was actually included in the pubsub message.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found a band-aid solution but I would prefer not to do it. I can copy what should be the message ID into the messageId field with this: message.setMessageId(message.get("message_id").toString()); Then I can use the getMessageId method but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Are you using push subscription?

Comment: Yes, we are using push subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not found another solution. The only thing I can do is copy what should be the message ID into the messageId field with this: message.setMessageId(message.get("message_id").toString()); Then I can use the getMessageId method. This is just a bug.